# How to sort a list of tuples which elements are of mixed nature?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

Say I have the following list:

```
mylist=[((0, 2), 4),
        ((0, 3), 9),
        ((0, 7), 49),
        ((0, 17), 50),
        ((0, 67), 85),
        ((0, 77), 98),
        ((1, 2), 1),
        ((1, 3), 4),
        ((1, 4), 9)]
```

How can I sort it based on the integer, stand-alone value within each tuple? Said values are, in the example, `4`, `9`, `49`, and so forth.

The result should be something like this:

```
  mylist=[((1, 2), 1)
            ((0, 2), 4),
            ((1, 3), 4),
            ((0, 3), 9),
            ((1, 4), 9)
            ((0, 7), 49),
            ((0, 17), 50),
            ((0, 67), 85),
            ((0, 77), 98)]
```

The order in which the `(x,y)` values in each tuple are sorted is irrelevant.

Comment: Use `itemgetter(1)`, as shown in Jamylak's answer in the linked duplicate question.

Comment: Wow, all of these down votes are great! Must have said something to be ashamed of. You are all ready to point your finger. A deeply sad jury, that's what you are.

Comment: You probably got those downvotes from people who considered that you didn't do adequate research on this question; I was not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sorted with a key lambda:

```
sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1])
```